# Is there a full example for SOCKit or other good State-Restore Libraries?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I really don't know how to implement saving and restoring application state and I thought using a library is a good idea. Is there a full example for SOCKit or are there other good helper library for iOS?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Do you mean application state or do you mean UI state?

Comment: I mean both. UI state there is something Apple helps you, but a full blown example would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keith Harrison has a good series on user interface state preservation and restoration using the iOS 6 APIs on his blog: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/categories/state-restoration/